# How to fix "businessObject not defined"

Tags: python-3.x, object, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, runtime-error

I am a newbie to Python and web scraping. To practice, I am just trying to pull some business names from some HTML tags a website. However, the code is not running and is throwing an 'object is not defined' error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://marketplace.akc.org/groomers/?location=Michigan&page=1'
response = requests.get(url, timeout = 5)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") 
for business in content.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "groomer-salon-card__details"}):
    businessObject = {
            "BusinessName": business.find('h4', attrs={"class": "groomer-salon-card__name"}).text.encode('utf-8')
    }   
print (businessObject)
```

Expected: I am trying to retrieve the business names from [this](https://marketplace.akc.org/groomers?location=Michigan&page=1) web page.

Result:

> NameError: name 'businessObject' is not defined

Comment: If `content.find_all` doesn't return anything, the for loop doesn't run and `businessObject` is never defined. You can define the variable as None before the loop: `businessObject = None`

Answer (score 1):

When you did

```
content.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "groomer-salon-card__details"})
```

you actually got an empty list as no match.

So, when you did

```
for business in content.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "groomer-salon-card__details"}):
```

you didn't generate

```
businessObject
```

As mentioned in comments, that led to your error.

Content is dynamically loaded from elswhere in the DOM using javascript (as well as other DOM modifications). You can still regex out the javascript object which contains the content used to update the DOM as you saw it in browser. You then parse with json parser as follows:

```
import requests, re, json

url = 'https://marketplace.akc.org/groomers/?location=Michigan&page=1'
response = requests.get(url, timeout = 5)
p = re.compile(r'state: (.*?)\n', re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(p.findall(response.text)[0])

for listing in data['content']['search_results']['pages']['data']:
    print(listing['organization_name'])
```

If you view page source on webpage you will see that the DOM is essentially dynamically populated from top to bottom with mutation observers monitoring progress.